# Current date in TypeORM and PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs

What's the best way to have a field for a date in PostgreSQL and TypeORM?

I'm relatively new in PostgreSQL (in general SQL database), but in MongoDB (with Mongoose) I usually have a field like this:

```js
export class User {
  @Prop({ default: Date.now() })
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

What would be the equivalent to this in TypeORM and PostgreSQL? Because, if I use this approach, PostgreSQL throws me an error.

> QueryFailedError: date/time field value out of range: "1634416004545"

Comment: Well `Date.now()` returns the `epoch` in milliseconds which cannot be directly used in a Postgres timestamp(tz) field. In Postgres you can do `select to_timestamp(1634416695294/1000); 2021-10-16 13:38:15-07`. For the ORM though you probably needs something that returns a parsed date/time string. Best choice is to return as ISO format. See [Date/time input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) for more information.

Answer (score 19):

I know it's an old one, but it's one I stumbled on today and with no approved answer, so I thought it could be of help to someone like me in the future.

Basically, the problem comes from using `Date.now()` instead of `new Date()`. My working example looks like this

```
  @Column({ type: "timestamptz", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
  createdDate: Date;
```

If the value is not provided, it will assign the current value. Note here that if you update a row and the new value misses the `createdDate` field, the old one will be overwritten.

Then if you want to set it manually, you simply use `new Date()` like this

```
const created = { ..., createdDate: new Date(), ...}
```

Comment: What if there's a discrepancy between SQL's time and the backend's time.  new Date() could be off.  It would be nice if we had a way to say: createdDate: typeorm.Utils.Date.NOW

Comment: In case you use `date` instead of `timestamptz`, you can use `() => 'CRRENT_DATE'` for the default value.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`@CreateDateColumn`](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/createdatecolumn) decorator to archieve what you want:

```js
export class User {
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but, how if I want to fill that manually? I mean, if I have a specific field that receives a Date and I want to send it in my service

Comment: Couldn't you just use `new User({ createdAt: $yourDate })`?